# Add new rows in a df depending on another df and conditions with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have some issues in order to create a new data frame depending on 2 dataframes informations. 
Here is a `dataframe1`:

```
species seq_names   value
dog     seq_C       0.67
cat     seq_F       1.4
cat     seq_E       0.4
dolphin seq_F       0.7
dolphin seq_A       1.9
frog    seq_A       0.8
frog    seq_B       0.40
```

Here is another `dataframe2` :

```
group_number    col1
1               cat
1               dog
2               dolphin
2               frog
2               seq_X
2               seq_Y
```

As you can see there are `2 groups`. And the idea is to add to these groups the `seq_names` depending on the species they matches in the df1 and their values.

Here I should get a `new_df` with the `seq_names` added:

```
group_number    sp_seq_names
1               cat
1               dog
1               seq_C
1               seq_F
1               seq_E   
2               dolphin
2               frog
2               seq_A
2               seq_B
2               seq_X
2               seq_Y
```

Edit for IMC : as you can see `seq_X` and `seq_Y` are still present at the end.

The `group_number 1` gained the seq_names `C,F and E` because all where matching with at least one species in the group. 
`But the subtlety is here`: As you can also see `group1` gained the s`eq_name F` but not the `group_number 2` despit the fact that `dolphin` was also matching this sequence, but the `cat` had a better value than `dolphin` with this `seq_name` (1.4 against 0.7.)
So the `group_number 2` only gained 2 `seq_names A and B.`

Does someone have an idea using pandas?

I tried something with a merge:

```
pd.merge(df2, df1, left_on=['col1'],right_on=['species'],how='outer')

   group_number     col1  species seq_names  value
0             1      cat      cat     seq_F   1.40
1             1      cat      cat     seq_E   0.40
2             1      dog      dog     seq_C   0.67
3             2  dolphin  dolphin     seq_F   0.70
4             2  dolphin  dolphin     seq_A   1.80
5             2     frog     frog     seq_B   0.40
6             2     frog     frog     seq_A   0.80
```

and then I created the desired df :

```
df=[]
for species, group  in  zip (df_new['seq_names'],df_new['group_number']):
 df.append({'groups':group,'sp_seq_names':species})
for species, group  in  zip (df_new['species'],df_new['group_number']):
 df.append({'groups':group,'sp_seq_names':species})
```

and I get :

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(df)
       col1  groups
0       cat       1
1       cat       1
2       dog       1
3   dolphin       2
4   dolphin       2
5      frog       2
6      frog       2
7     seq_F       1
8     seq_E       1
9     seq_C       1
10    seq_F       2
11    seq_A       2
12    seq_B       2
13    seq_A       2
```

But as you can see I cannot manage to take the sharing seq_names between groups and decide which group gain this seq_name according to the value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test')
df2 = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df2 = df2.rename(columns={'col1' : 'species'})
print(df)
#    species seq_names  value
# 0      dog     seq_C   0.67
# 1      cat     seq_F   1.40
# 2      cat     seq_E   0.40
# 3  dolphin     seq_F   0.70
# 4  dolphin     seq_A   1.90
# 5     frog     seq_A   0.80
# 6     frog     seq_B   0.40

print(df2)
#    group_number  species
# 0             1      cat
# 1             1      dog
# 2             2  dolphin
# 3             2     frog

#   We now don't immediatly drop the duplicates, we want to save the merge before.
#   Doing this, we're able to keep the seq_names associated with their group_number.
ndf = df.merge(df2, on='species')\
        .sort_values(by='value', ascending=False)

#   I make a copy so that I get a whole new DataFrame.
#   If I didn't. Changes made to seq_groups would have affected the original.
seq_groups_df = ndf[['seq_names', 'group_number']].copy()
seq_groups_df = seq_groups_df.rename(columns={'seq_names' : 'sp_seq_names'})
print(seq_groups_df)
#   seq_names  group_number
# 4     seq_A             2
# 1     seq_F             1
# 5     seq_A             2
# 3     seq_F             2
# 0     seq_C             1
# 2     seq_E             1
# 6     seq_B             2

ndf = ndf.drop_duplicates(subset='seq_names', keep='first')

#   Either select the interesting columns.
ndf = ndf[['group_number', 'species']]
ndf = ndf.rename(columns={'species' : 'sp_seq_names'})

print(ndf)
#    group_number sp_seq_names
# 4             2      dolphin
# 1             1          cat
# 0             1          dog
# 2             1          cat
# 6             2         frog


result_df = ndf.append(seq_groups_df).reset_index(drop=True)
print(result_df)
#     group_number sp_seq_names
# 0              2      dolphin
# 1              1          cat
# 2              1          dog
# 3              1          cat
# 4              2         frog
# 5              2        seq_A
# 6              1        seq_F
# 7              2        seq_A
# 8              2        seq_F
# 9              1        seq_C
# 10             1        seq_E
# 11             2        seq_B
```

Comment: Hello @IMCoins, thank you for your help but the output should be juste composed of 2 columns (col1 (species in your exemple) and groups) as the 3th df I show in my exemple (I called it new_df).

Comment: @chippycentra I edited my answer to better suits your needs. I invite you to accept the answer if it answers your question :)

Comment: `seq_names` and `species_names` should be in the same data frame because in the column  `sp_seq_names ` we should see both seq_names and species_names as the `new_df` shows.

Comment: Ho in fact I edited the question, in the dataframe2 I can also already have seq_names and I need to keep them. I edited the files and the desired output. Sorry... (I made a note for you in the post) I added seq_X and seq_Y in the df2 to explain it.

Comment: Well I found a way by using: `ndf[ndf['seq_names'].isnull() | ~ndf[ndf['seq_names'].notnull()].duplicated(subset='seq_names',keep='first')]`